# MS Access 2013: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: wpf, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, anycpu

We are running windows 8 64 bit and MS Office 2013 64 bit on a virtual machine. I got this error when I am trying to query the access database with parameters in the query string. The stack trace is:

```
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.ICommandText.Execute(IntPtr pUnkOuter, Guid& riid, tagDBPARAMS pDBParams, IntPtr& pcRowsAffected, Object& ppRowset)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at _64AccessTest.MainWindow.Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\xiaosu\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\64AccessTest\64AccessTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 110
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at _64AccessTest.App.Main() in c:\Users\xiaosu\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\64AccessTest\64AccessTest\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I have got the following code:

```
    var connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\templates\64Access.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
   using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
      connection.Open();
      const String query = "PARAMETERS @Id LONG; select * from Subject where Id = @Id";
      OleDbCommand _command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
      _command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer);
      _command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 1;
      using (OleDbDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader()){
          ......
      }
   }
```

The exception occurs at this line: using (OleDbDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader()

We are running .NET 4 with Visual Studio 2012 and this is a WPF application.

The wired thing is if I do not pass parameters to the sql query, it works fine. Once the query has some parameters, the error occurs.

In Visual Studio, the platform is set to AnyCPU which is what we want. We do not want to change this to x86.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Leave .Net out of the picture until after you have a query which works when tested directly in an Access session ... perhaps this one: `PARAMETERS [@Id] LONG; select * from Subject where Id = [@Id]`

Comment: @HansUp, the query works in Access perfectly. Thanks for the advice anyway.